# Why does a Bluetooth LE Scan include unknown duplicates?

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth

When I perform a Bluetooth LE Scan on my Raspberry Pi 4B (Debian Bullseye) with `hcitool` why does it include `(unknown)` entries with the same MAC address as an already listed named item?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...
12:5E:EE:76:58:72 (unknown)
30:1B:97:75:D2:9B (unknown)
30:1B:97:75:D3:42 (unknown)
30:1B:97:75:D3:42 BLE Device 3891BA
C6:F6:7F:1F:6A:5A LE_WH-1000XM4
C6:F6:7F:1F:6A:5A (unknown)
30:1B:97:75:D2:9B BLE Device 6523F1
```

For example `30:1B:97:75:D3:42` appears twice as `(unknown)` and `BLE Device 3891BA`.

Comment: The first thing to mention is that hcitool was [deprecated by the BlueZ project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) in 2017. The correct tool now to do the scanning is `bluetoothctl`. Bluetooth scans can either be passive or active. With active scans there is an additional `scan response` packet from the device. The BLE device name can be given by the content of the initial Advertising data packet and/or the content of the Scan Response. I suspect what you are seeing is the name is only in the scan response packet.

Comment: @ukBaz Sounds like a decent answer if you have time -- although you may not know "for sure" if that is why, the reasoning seems pretty solid.

Comment: Maybe the original poster can have `sudo btmon` running in a separate terminal to get more detailed information on what packets are being received. It is a very verbose output but hopefully searching for the BT address will easily find the packets of interest. `sudo btmon -w btsnoop.log` will write a file of a format that be read in to [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) network analysis tool if you are more familiar with that